# C# Quick bit array

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitarray

as stated in the title i am evaluating the cost of implement a BitArray over bytes[] (i have understood that native BitArray is pretty slow) insthead of using a string representation of bits (eg : "001001001" ) but i am open to any suggestion that are more effective.

The length of array is not known at design time, but i suppose may be between 200 and 500 bit per array.

Memory is not a concern, so use a lot of memory for represent the array is not an issue, what matter is speed when array is created and manupulated (thiy will be manipulated a lot).

Thanks in advance for yours consideration and suggenstion onto the topic.

Comment: `BitArray` is **not** slower than what you may do using directly `byte[]` (because it does exactly what you would do). If you worry about performance I wouldn't even _think_ to use strings...

Comment: Have you even tried benchmarking whether `BitArray` is too slow for your needs? It sounds like you're trying to prematurely optimise code that doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: Code that use string already exist, and i woud speed it up using some other kind of representation.
As stated here : http://www.dotnetperls.com/bitarray they are not a good option when speed is required.
So i have considered array of bytes, but i don't know if there are better options or if bit strings are even better than array of bytes.

Comment: Strings? There's no point in even trying. Using a plain old `bool[]` may be faster than a `BitArray`, otherwise you're not going to have much luck.

Comment: The `BitArray` type is "slow" because the bits are packed into ints. This means that every bitwise operation require some extra operations to update the int containing the bit. However, this representation is optimal with regard to space and the overhead will in many cases be insignificant. If you do not care about space just use `bool[]` or `byte[]`. Strings are very bad because they are immutable and every change will require creation of a new string with slightly modified contents.

Comment: @harold and Marti Liversage : it seems that bool[] arrays give to me the better trade off (efficency vs simplicity). I suppose i will procede in that way.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

A few suggestions:

1) Computers don't process bits o even n int or long will work at the same speed

2) To reach speed you can consider writing it with unsafe code

3) New is expensive. If the objects are created a lot you can do the following: Create a bulk of 10K 
objects at a time and  serve them from a  method when required. Once the cache runs out you can recreate them. Have another method that once an object processing completes you clean it up and return it to the cache

4) Make sure your manipulation is optimal